# Microsoft Interop Word Get Range from Heading

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I am looking to be able to get a range within a Word template from the Headings/Sections shown in the bookmarks.

For the template I have, I have multiple headings templated out and I need to automate the insertion to the document.

[image: Example]

So, say I wanted to insert text under each heading without searching for the text (as this will likely change) how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to add bookmarks to my template on the paragraph after and then use this to get the range:

```
Word.Range range = wordDoc.Bookmarks[bookmarkName].Range;
```

I can then use `range.Text = text` to insert the text.